# How to re-size captcha area?

Tags: css

```
#recaptcha_area, #recaptcha_table {
    width: 280px !important;
}
```

default width of captcha is 318px. I want to decrease its size to 280px.
But my css code is not working.

Comment: Hello userxy. Welcome to stackoverflow. Before posting your questions please look at the FAQ of this site. We are not a free ask-it-all-and-solve-my-problems site. Try to be respectful to the users who try to help. freely. If you dont even find the time to create a more meaningful username and even less try to point out your problem correctly you will probably not get too many helpers dedicate their time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well your question is proberbly too broad because you did not tell which captcha software you are using and how your html does look like.

Just some general hints:

If you use recaptcha (which I guess by the css classes) you cannot customize the captcha, because it loads a iframe which you cannot control or modify. This behavior is caused by the same orgin policy, which prevents accessing pages from other domains.

The only hack I could guess is using the `zoom` attribute, but I'm not sure and I never tried it on iframes.

Alternative you could try using `transform:scale(x)` which should work, however I never got good results with transform yet.